# Use of unresolved identifier 'UINavigationBarAppearance' in Xcode 10.3 iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I have been trying to access the below code and I got this error I didn't find any solution.

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
```

> Use of unresolved identifier 'UINavigationBarAppearance'; did you mean 'UINavigationBarDelegate'?

Comment: You can't use iOS 13 APIs in Xcode 10. You need Xcode 11.

Comment: follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58688422/3359299

Comment: thank you @rmaddy your comment helped me resolving my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @rmaddy `UINavigationBarAppearance` is available for iOS 13.0+ as per the Apple's documentation. Refer to [UINavigationBarAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbarappearance).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UINavigationBar.appearance()` to configure NavigationBar for all iOS versions in Xcode 10.