# Problem with NavBar in iOS 13 doesn't show

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have this problem with Navigation Bar in iOS 13. In this iOS version doesn't show correctly but in other version show normally.

This is the problem.

**iOS 13**
[image: Navbar in iOS 13]

**iOS 11**
[image: NavBar in iOS 11.1]

Anybody know what is the problem.

This is code of my AppDelegate. `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` (I don't use a storyboard)

```
InitViewController *viewController = [[InitViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
navController.navigationBar.opaque = YES;
navController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: I think you have problem with constraints. Do you use SafeArea for top constraints?

Comment: have you added any constraint to navBar ?

Comment: How to add this constraints?

Comment: issue is with ios 13 or earlier versions ?

Comment: In my case is only in iOS 13

Comment: iOS version or problem with iPhone with notch?

Comment: The problem is in iOS 13 doesn't show the NavBar.

Comment: can you show us some code please -- specifically how youre embedding your view controller into the nav controller and also any customizations you're doing to it? theres probably a bug in your code somewhere.

Comment: But I don't know why in iOS 12, 11 the nav bar show correctly but in iOS 13 doesn't work correctly. Is the same code.

Comment: Take a look to my extension in Swift https://stackoverflow.com/a/58361273/5575955

Comment: how did you present this view controller? Check if not modally or something else in this direction