# Set border and color of navigationbar when largetitles = true

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I set my navigation bar with **preferslargetitles = true**. For some reason, the color and the bottom border disappear and it's white. How can I keep the color and the border of this like if it's standard?

This is how it looks like with large titles:

[image]

I would like to have the same color and border as in this:

[image]

I already tried to set the background color, but the border is still missing and the status bar is in a different color.

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 248/255, green: 248/255, blue: 248/255, alpha: 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work now. If anyone has the same problem it can be done with this code:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 248/255, green: 248/255, blue: 248/255, alpha: 1)
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
        appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]

        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .systemBlue
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
} else {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .systemBlue
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 248/255, green: 248/255, blue: 248/255, alpha: 1)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
}
```

You need to put this in

> func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool { }

otherwise, the first view controller does not have these changes, because the first view is already loaded.

Thanks to @Sebastion who post something similar in this post: [iOS13 Navigation bar large titles not covering status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56910797/ios13-navigation-bar-large-titles-not-covering-status-bar)