# Present UIViewController not showing completely

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

Presenting UIViewController from UITabBarViewController~>RootViewController.

```
let uploadViewController = UIStoryboard.identifier(.Home).instantiateViewController(identifier: "UploadViewController") as! UploadViewController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: uploadViewController)
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
navigationController.statusBar(colour: .ThemeColor)
self.present(navigationController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

//UploadViewcontroller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.addCrossAction()
    setTitle(text: "Upload")

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func addCrossAction(){
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .ThemeColor
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    navigationController?.navigationBar.hide_NavigationBar_BottonLine()
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "crossButtonWhite"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(crossButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
}
```

Observer that the NavigationBar Not completed displayed..

Please find below Image.

[image]

How to have complete blue .ThemeColor NavigationBar.

Comment: Change status bar background color. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60150062/14733292

Comment: there found Extenstion which helps

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .ThemeColor
```

try:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .ThemeColor
```

or (iOS >13):

```
UINavigationBarAppearance().backgroundColor = .ThemeColor
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want total blue bar with large title

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```

otherwise set a dummy view with ThemeColor background on top of your table view and anchor the table to dummy view bottom, before assign to your navbar bg color to clear.

Declare your dummyView:

```
let dummyView = UIView()
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
dummyView.backgroundColor = .ThemeColor
dummyView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(dummyView)
dummyView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
dummyView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
dummyView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
dummyView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

after that assign tableView top constraints to dummyView bottom constraints...
if You search an extension to set your navBar programmatically, take a look to my https://stackoverflow.com/a/58361273/5575955