# How to change bar tint color that covers the notch area on swift (uikit)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, navigationbar

I'm trying to change the `barTintColor` from `SceneDelegate`, but it does not cover the whole top area. take a look at my ss:

[image]

How can I make it covers the entire top area?

Here's my code, thank you in advance.

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 47/225, green: 54/225, blue: 64/225, alpha: 1.0)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 47/225, green: 54/225, blue: 64/225, alpha: 1.0)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, apparently it's because the iOS version. Pre iOS 13 can work with just

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .yellow
```

But now it's a bit different. SO to this guy, i found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56910797/ios13-navigation-bar-large-titles-not-covering-status-bar)

So what I do now is:

```
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.backgroundColor = .red

    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance // for scrolling bg color
    UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance // not sure why it's here, but u can remove it and still works
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance // for large title bg color
```

that is at least work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in just one line:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .yellow
```

Comment: in my case, it did not change the background color during large title, but it did change to yellow when I scroll it

Comment: Have you got a custom view that's covering the status bar?

Comment: Found it, check my answer. Thanks for responding.